# Form with pleny of textboxes and Formatted text crashes [C#]

Tags: c#, text, textbox, crash, format

I am developing an application that requires to load lots of textboxes dynamically. It may vary according to certain conditions. And each one of these textboxes' text is formatted differently: Some of them will have their text in Bold, some of them underlined, and so on. Kind of like a document.
All of these textboxes are included in a flowlayoutpanel, and this flowlayoutpanel's flow is up to down and autoscrollable. So when i scroll down the "document", everything goes blank for some reason, there are white lines and rectangles all over the textboxes and then, the application crashes.

[Screenshot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEzKH.png)

Sometimes it might throw a Generic GDI+ error exception, some others an Out of Memory exception. So I decided to try out putting all of these textboxes without the format (just the text with no bold/italic/underlined styling), and it works just fine like that.

My question is: Is there a way to prevent these type of errors without having to remove the format from the text? If not, could there be another approach to this?

I'd highly appreciate good feedback on this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen that sort of problem with a low quality graphics card.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some information if you want anyone to have a chance at assisting you.  Copy your existing project and slowly remove stuff until the problem stops happening.  Then add back the last thing (so that the problem occurs).  Then provide source, and a description of how to reproduce the issue.  Right now, it reads like someone who says "Hey, I was driving and I noticed my windshield was cracked - any idea how that might have happened?"